# comparar tabelas sql exibindo resultado diferente

Tags: php, sql, tabela-banco-de-dados

Tenho uma consulta sql que relaciona duas tabelas:

cadastro e liberar.

tenho uma aplicação que adiciona os "id" de "cadastro" na tabela "liberar",
eu pretendo exibir somente os resultados que NÃO existem na tabela "liberar".

segue a consulta:

```
$verifica = $db->prepare("SELECT liberar.aluno AS alunoID, liberar.title, cadastro.nome AS name, cadastro.id AS idAluno FROM cadastro INNER JOIN liberar ON (cadastro.id = liberar.aluno) WHERE liberar.title = ? GROUP BY cadastro.nome ORDER BY cadastro.nome");
    $verifica->execute(array($identificador));
```

Essa variavel $identificador é o title que eu capturo pelo GET.
essa consulta me retorna os ids que foram adicionados em liberar, porém quero retornar os que não estão adicionados somente.

já tentei trocar (cadastro.id != liberar.aluno) mas assim ele me retorna todos os id, eu preciso que retorne somente os ids que foram enviados para liberar..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A consulta abaixo retorna todos os cadastros que não exista registro na tabela liberar:

```
SELECT
    cadastro.id
 FROM
     cadastro
 WHERE
       NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM liberar where liberar.aluno =  cadastro.id )
 GROUP BY
     cadastro.nome
 ORDER BY
     cadastro.nome
```

No entanto não dá para filtrar pelo liberar.title pois o title existe apenas na tabela liberar, e nos registros que você quer não existem  a itens na tabelas liberar.

Comment: isso resolveu, obrigado! Postei a adaptação do meu codigo.

Answer (score 0):

Vou colocar dois exemplos onde quero clientes que não tenham vendas

```
1 - 

SELECT DISTINCT.* FROM CLIENTES C
LEFT JOIN VENDAS V ON(V.CODID = C.CODID)
WHERE (V.CODID IS NULL)

2 - 

SELECT DISTINCT C.* FROM CLIENTES
WHERE (CODID NOT IN(SELECT CODID FROM VENDAS))
```

Os dois trazem o mesmo resultado, o que muda é a performance dependendo da quantidade de registros em cada tabela

Supondo que a tabela CLIENTES seja enorme, o primeiro exemplo será mais lento, caso seja a VENDAS o segundo exemplo será mais lento

Deve-se levar em contas os devidos ÍNDICES criados em cada tabela e os filtros adicionais na clausula WHERE

Answer (score 0):

Resolvido com a dica do Marciano Machado, obrigado!

> NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM liberar WHERE aluno =  cadastro.id )

```
"SELECT cadastro.*, liberar.* FROM cadastro INNER JOIN liberar WHERE liberar.title = ? AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM liberar WHERE aluno =  cadastro.id ) GROUP BY cadastro.nome ORDER BY cadastro.nome"
$verifica->execute(array($identificador));
```

Eu adaptei dessa forma: 
inclui a junção das tabelas para recuperar o "title" pois é o title que eu recupero pela variavel $identificador no GET, essa variavel filtra a consulta por titulo, já que a aplicação terá titulos baseados em matérias da escola.